# Using Digi 002 with Yamaha MG24

Tags: home, studio, upgrade

I am upgrading my home studio from a two channel mbox to the 002.  I made a patch bay to go to the front of my rack for inputs (front vs back issue solved).  In an effort to get the cleanest sound into Pro Tools, I am going into 002 rack first then out using outputs on interface on back to mixer to control mix on console to control room and FOH (looking to do some live recording).  My problem is I am not getting any signal from outputs on back of 002 whether I plug a mono instrument cable to mixer or balanced TRS to XLR to mixer.  Either way nothing.

My other choice is going into mixer first then to 002 rack.  But I don't like the idea of passing thru mixer first when recording live.  But I can control the live mix (most important). I also have a question on which cable will be best coming from i/o (my only out on Yamaha MG24) to 002 rack for best recording.

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned the outputs from within the I/O menu in Pro Tools?

With regards to configuration I would suggest bypassing the patch bay and sending groups 1 - 4 on the Yamaha to the line inputs 1-4 on the 002, and then, if you need to, you can send mixes from the Yamaha, or plug straight into the mic inputs on the 002.

You could then use auxes 1-4 on the Yamaha for the additional 4 line inputs of the 002.

Finally, I would send all of the line outputs from the 002 as line inputs 19-24 on the Yamaha.

Answer (score 1):

It was my output assignments.  They were still configured for Stereo Out instead of multiple outputs.  The TRS to XLR Hosa interconnect cable works perfect for connection to board.  Looks like I am set until the Digimax D8 comes in.  Then I will need to add the additional ins/outs.  Thanks for the tip.